# Emacs fullscreen on LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, emacs, fullscreen

It seems the <kbd>F11</kbd> is not bound for fullscreen. I am using Emacs24 on Ubuntu 14.04, when I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> i get the message: `/bin/bash: wmctrl: command not found`. How can I bind the <kbd>F11</kbd> key for fullscreening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message

```
/bin/bash: wmctrl: command not found
```

install the necessary package

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Answer (score 0):

From the **emacs wiki**, use this command to toggle full screen mode for Ubuntu.

```
(run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil 'toggle-fullscreen)
```

Using keybindings you can bind this command to the <kbd>F11</kbd>.